# How can I hide a UIBarButtonItem after a Button is touched on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a normal table view with many cells, each cell has a button on
it and when clicked/touched on it a menuBarItem shifts to a lower position.
I suspect this is some backButton, but even this line has no effect from the viewDidload TableViewConroller.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

If I can hide this button my problem will be solved, but I am struggling to reference the bar item from within the cell where I present a share dialog.

Thanks.

code that fails...

```
UIActivityViewController *act = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]  initWithActivityItems:@[@"mjk",_dest] applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

act.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[act.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];// has no effect
[act.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];// has no effect
 act.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil; // has no effect
 act.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil; // has no effect
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the delegate/protocol pattern? You could, conceivably create a protocol that defines a `shareButtonTapped:` method and have your view controller implement this protocol. Then each time you create/dequeue a cell could set a `delegate` on the cell be an instance of the view controller and thus establish the connection between your cells and the view controller. There are other ways you could pull this off, too.

Comment: You may have other issues going on too, but its hard to say w/o looking at your code directly.

Answer (score 2):

For Objective-C 
You can use

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

if it is not in navigation bar and you are using custom cell. Change the button type to `UIButton` and `myButton.hidden = YES;` will solve your case

Comment: my UITableViewCell does not have a reference to the navigationItem.

Comment: Where do you add the button(the one you want to hide)? In navigation bar or in cell?

Comment: in the cell, I have tried passing a reference to each cell, and this does
work - but it seems so wrong to do it this way.